# BubbleSort in R Program on Specific column

Tags: r, csv, bubble-sort

How to apply bubble sort to a specific column of csv File and apply bubble sort function and obtain the csv file data based on order of the column in Rstudio.
Please help me with this

Input:

```
Daniel,New York,23456,Gaming
Melinda,Washington,45678,Sports
Dave,Chicago,12345,Hiking
Ross,Boston,34567,Chess
```

Output:

```
Ross,Boston,34567,Chess
Dave,Chicago,12345,Hiking
Daniel,New York,23456,Gaming
Melinda,Washington,45678,Sports
```

Comment: Why would you use an inefficient sorting algorithm?

Comment: I wanted to perform sorting on  column it can be any type of sorting like basically we need to define sorting function explicitly and pass the column and get the data

Comment: So, this is your homework?

Comment: Can you post an example dataset and your efforts so far?

Answer (score 0):

Function `order` can be helpful for this:

```
# some test data
x <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100), ncol=5))

# origonal order
x

# order by colum "X1"
ndx <- order(x$X1)

# reorder complete data frame
x[ndx, ]
```